# Chrome Extension: How to remove content script CSS after injection?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to remove CSS file `styles.css` injected from content_scripts (manifest.json)

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
  "css": ["styles.css"],
  "js": ["jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "content.js"]
}],
```

Some explanation for I want to do in my extension.

At first `styles.css` is loaded and it changes some code on the page. It works.

Then, the user wants to click on the button and turn off extension. It works.

But then `styles.css` has to be removed. It doesn't work.

And after some times user wants to turn on extension and `styles.css` has to be added again.

When I tried to solve it like this:

```
var style = document.createElement('link');
style.rel = 'stylesheet';
style.type = 'text/css';
style.href = chrome.extension.getURL('myStyles.css');
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(style);
```

it did not work well, because when the extension is getting started then page will be flicker for a few milliseconds.

Comment: Question is closed. I'm bore. Thanks.

Comment: Does "Question is closed" mean that you no longer are wondering about this topic because you no longer care (for a reason other than you found a solution), or that you found a solution to the problem, or something else?  If you found a solution to the problem, then you should post an Answer to this Question.  [Self-answered questions are encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: So. yes. I tell about solution a little later :)

Comment: Yes, please do share your solution so others don't spend time coming up with solutions unnecessarily for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked and have found a solution for this problem.

**manifest.json**

```
manifest.json

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
    "js": ["jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "content.js"],
    "run_at" : "document_start" // It runs content.js first until page loads
  }],

  "web_accessible_resources": ["styles.css"] // It provides styles.css for use in content.js
```

and **content.js**

```
function loadCSS(file) {
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.href = chrome.extension.getURL('css/' + file + '.css');
    link.id = file;
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].appendChild(link);
}

function unloadCSS(file) {
  var cssNode = document.getElementById(file);
  cssNode && cssNode.parentNode.removeChild(cssNode);
}
```

**content.js** only loads the file.css (styles.css which was provided) in html tag until page loads

Comment: So the only real difference between "don't suggest code like X" and your code is `run_at`?

Comment: Yes. At first I ran code with `"run_at" : "document_end"` ( this is default) and happened flicker. Then I found instriction `"run_at" : "document_start"` and all works so good. Just I don't knew about it I recently met with the google API.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect that better and I'll upvote your answer.